# how can I use monaca plugin with monaca localkit?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am using monaca localkit to build mobile application and connect my android mobile as debugger so I can test every thing on my mobile beside to the mobile simulator that exist in monaca localkit.
now I want to use cordova plugin (camera to take pictures) with my application.
I read many document "how to use monaca plugin"
all documents talk about install monaca (some thing like npm install -g cordova)
how can I do that on my mobile?
I tried to download the java script files to my project but there are many missed files (like cordova_plugins.js)
how can I use cordova camera with monaca localkit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Localkit, you just need to select the project, click on the `Build Settings` and, once the window has opened, go to `Cordova Plugins`. Once you updated, just close the settings window and you are ready to go.

If you want to use the custom plugins on Monaca Debugger, remember to build a Custom Debugger and install it on your device.

Comment: when I press Build Settings I get an popup window with just two charecters in it **{ }**. I am using Monaca Localkit 2.1.3 with windows 10